# Spring threw load exception(java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:)

Tags: eclipse, spring

I am trying to run a simple jsp program in eclipse but when i run the program i get following errors.I am working with spring now and i have added all the jars properly in the right path.The jsp program is as follows

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
   <body>
    <h1>WELCOME TO EMPLOYEE ACCESS SITE.PLEASE ENTER THE FOLLOWING INFORMATION</h1>
    <form:form method="POST" action="/Spring/mvc1/addStudent">
    <table>
     <tr>
       <td><form:label path="name">Name</form:label></td>
       <td><form:input path="name" /></td>
     </tr>

     <tr>
       <td><form:label path="id">id</form:label></td>
       <td><form:input path="id" /></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td colspan="2">
         <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
       </td>
     </tr>
    </table>  
 </form:form>
  </body>
</html>
```

and when i run this above program i get the following set of error

```
SEVERE: Servlet /Spring threw load() exception
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.context.ConfigurableWebApplicationContext.setId(Ljava/lang/String;)V
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:454)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:483)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:358)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:325)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:127)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1161)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:981)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4058)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4364)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:719)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:516)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:578)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
Mar 27, 2013 11:02:15 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Mar 27, 2013 11:02:15 AM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
Mar 27, 2013 11:02:15 AM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/109  config=null
Mar 27, 2013 11:02:15 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 2471 ms
Mar 27, 2013 11:02:23 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No WebApplicationContext found: no   
ContextLoaderListener registered?
at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(WebApplicationContextUtils.java:84)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(RequestContextUtils.java:81)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContext.initContext(RequestContext.java:219)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.JspAwareRequestContext.initContext(JspAwareRequestContext.java:74)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.JspAwareRequestContext.<init>(JspAwareRequestContext.java:48)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:76)
at org.apache.jsp.mvc11.student_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fform_005f0(student_jsp.java:104)
at org.apache.jsp.mvc11.student_jsp._jspService(student_jsp.java:73)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:374)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:337)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:266)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:286)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

I havent linked the jsp page to spring class yet.I just wanted to see the front end display.I am not sure where the problem is...

Comment: Did you try what I explained in answer below?

Answer (score 0):

Your JSP page should be returned by Spring Controller. It would work if you had no spring form tags in JSP, but your form in JSP has tags which require name and id paths. They should be coming from a bean. So you need to pass that bean/POJO along with the JSP. Add bean in the `Model` object.

Code would be something like this : 
Suppose page URL is : `http://localhost:8484/yourappcontext/student`

```
@Controller
public class StudentController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/student", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showAddStudentPage(Model model) {

        // instantiate empty student pojo containing name & id needed by JSP
        Student student = new Student();

        // add student pojo in model being sent with JSP
        model.addSttribute("student", student);

        return "addStudent"; // this would be your JSP name.
    }
}
```